# Get a distinct row count from another column

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SQL Table is as follows:

```
Category | Subcategory |  
A          1
A          1
A          2
B          1
B          2
```

I need the number of each subcategory for each category, not including duplicate subcategories within the category.

You'll notice there are 3 total "1" subcategories, but only a count of 2 as the duplicate is redundant and not included.

Example output:

```
subcategory | count
1             2
2             2
```

How can I achieve this? I am familiar with COUNT but I can only get the raw number of rows.

Using Snowflake.

Thanks!

Comment: `count(distinct Subcategory)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUP BY`, as in:

```
select Category, count(distinct Subcategory)
from t
group by Category
```